# Change Tracking on a mirrored database in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, mirror, change-tracking, database-mirroring

I'm working on a datawarehouse on a SQL Server 2012 Standard. For the benefit of our ETL process I want to enable Change Tracking. This is easily done, but this server is mirrored on another SQL Server 2012.

What are the consequences for the mirrored server? Will change tracking be enabled on the mirrored server as well? Do I have to take extra steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will be enabled on the mirrored database and no, you should not have additional configurations to set to get change tracking enabled in a mirror.  You are probably already aware that SQL server just stores the change data in a series of system tables (one per table enabled for change tracking).

As far as consequences for using this across a mirror, the added change data would also need to be propagated across the network to the mirror as well as the extra space taken up by the change tables would also be taken up on the mirror other than those I'm not aware of other consequences.